# Parent-Child List in Sharepoint Hosted Add-In in 2013

Tags: sharepoint, add-in

I have been trying to find a way to display the data in parent-child form using SharePoint Add-in. I have two lists: Master and Detail. Master list contains shortcode, description. Detail list contains Name, email address, user name.

I would like to display the data in something like this:

```
Short Code: SS
Description: Super Star

Name                          Email Address                  User Name

Andy                           andy@test.com
Mark                           mark@test.com
```

In the above example:

1. Shortcode and description are from master table
2. Name, Email Address, Username are from detailed table.
3. There must be a provision to add many detailed records in edit form
   for the same record (when I click on edit button).
4. There must be a provision to delete detailed record(if not required)
   from the grid with delete button on each row.

I am a newbie to SharePoint and it is mandatory requirement to use Add-ins for the above solution.